# CarrierWave Undefined Method `gsub` when calling process resize_to_fit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am working with CarrierWave and in my uploader I have `process :resize_to_fit => [1334,1334]`. When I comment this line out everything works fine, when I uncomment it I get the error `undefined method 'gsub' for nil:NilClass`. I have included CarrierWave::MiniMagick and from my understanding that is all that is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that hits this issue, it is related to the `Kernel#open_uri_original_open` method in Ruby 2.2.0. If you switch to an older version of Ruby such as `2.1.x` it will fix the problem. The actual issue isn't with CarrierWave, but with MiniMagick.